# Using IsolatedStorage in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, isolatedstorage

I am attempting to build an application using Xamarin's Mono stuff (MonoTouch and MonoDroid). I am trying to write some code that will allow me to place content in local storage. Coming from a Windows Phone background, I thought this was the recommended approach in the Xamarin world also. On Windows Phone, I would have done the following:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings clientStorage = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if (clientStorage != null)
{
  if (clientStorage.Contains("myKey"))
    clientStorage["myKey"] = value;
  else
    clientStorage.Add("myKey", value);
  clientStorage.Save();
}
```

While the Xamarin stack provides `System.IO.IsolatedStorage`, it does not provide the `IsolatedStorageSettings` class. Now, I feel stuck and I cannot find an example. My question is, how do I put a value in Isolated Storage in a Mono app?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IsolatedStorageSettings is not implemented in the mobile solutions](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1674#c10). It looks like it can be added, per that post, but it would have to be a custom implementation.

Generally though, you have a few other options.

- Use the native supported mechanisms. Android: SharedPreferences [(example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404031/165093). iOS: NSUserSettings
  [(example)](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/AppPrefs/Settings.cs).
- Store settings in a serialized object using JSON or XML and then
  deserialize the object when you need access to it. There will
  probably a good quick and dirty option, but not recommended.
- Use a SQLite database to store your settings. This would be a more
  cross platform option and probably the most recommended option.

Answer (score 0):

The official mono project provides an implementation for IsolatedStorageSettings.

You can find it at: https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/IsolatedStorageSettings.cs.

Just add the file to your project and add "System.Runtime.Serialization" to your references.

The class creates a file "__LocalSettings" in the app directory and uses the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) to serialize your settings.

Comment: It would be nice to see a little more explanation with this answer.